# OCaml fold_tree and confusing recursion

Tags: recursion, ocaml

If somebody may help me to understand this code:

```
let rec fold_tree f (T(x,l))=
  f x (map (fold_tree f) l);;
```

How it works? I mean mainly recursion.

Comment: It might be clearer if you included the definition of your tree type, and changed `map` to `List.map`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing a fold function for trees I'd be trying to define something of type `('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a tree -> b -> b`. That is, the function to be folded would take the value from a tree node and an accumulated value and produce a new accumulated value. (The interesting question then would be the order to visit the nodes.)

In this `fold_tree`, the function to be folded has type `('a -> 'b list -> 'b)`. That is, it takes a list of accumulated values instead of a single one. That makes it a little clumsy to use.

However, it does work after a fashion. In essence the definition says the following in prose: for a leaf, call your function `f` passing it the node value `x` and an empty list. For a non-leaf, first call yourself recursively on all the subtrees, then call the function `f` passing it the node value and the list of results of the recursive calls.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your data type declaration to be the following :

```
type 'a ntree = T of 'a * 'a ntree list;;
```

Now the best way to figure it out is :
1- take a look to it type signature,

```
val fold_tree : ('a -> 'b list -> 'b) -> 'a ntree -> 'b = <fun>
```

2 - Write a test case, according to the type signature,

```
let test_rtree = T("a", [ T("b", []) ; T("c", [ T ("f", [])]) ; T("d", [])])  
in fold_tree (List.fold_left (^)) test_rtree;;
- : string = "abcfd"
```

3 - Take a paper a pencil and try to reproduce the output of the test case.